# ¿Porque se me cierra la aplicacion al querer poner anuncios admob?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola a todos estoy tratando de poner anuncios admob en mi aplicacion, pero al querer ejecutarlo se me cierra la aplicacion con un mensaje que me indica que dejo de funcionar.

Les dejo los codigo para ayudarme a indicar mi error.
desde ya muchas gracias..

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

en el build.gradle declaro la dependcia

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

ManActivity

```
private PublisherAdView mAdView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_layaout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: hola **Yonathan Culzoni**, ya hiciste el debugging?. Ese error se puede deber a  varias cosa, el no controlar el retorno null de alguna variable que se usara, el Id no es valido, etc. Tuve el mismo problema mi aplicación se instalaba y tan pronto abría se cerraba, y no sabia porque, hice el debuggin y encontré que no estaba controlando en una linea de código cuando me retornaba null, no se si es tu caso,

Comment: Hola, si lo hice. ahora tambien le otorgue el permiso de internet en el manifest

Comment: lo volevere hacer para ver si me aparece algun error. gracias

Comment: Meta, me comentas como te fue

Comment: lo volvi hacer y ahora si me salio error pero no se como resolverlo ..  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\yonat\AppData\Local\Temp\ijmiscinit1.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:downloadSources_9d34d301-9721-4441-beab-cff2fd00169e'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:18.2.0@aar.
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info

Comment: at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxi.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:27)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6618                           Me sale estos dos errores en especial pero no lo puedo solucionar

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que se cierra? , me parece que nunca inicia por los errores que comentas @YonathanCulzoni

Comment: SI tenes razon directamente no inicia, como lo puedo resolver?